# Is there another default address than 192.168.1.1 for WRT54g routers?

Tags: wrt54gl

Anyone knows if there is another address I can use to access a brand new WRT54g router? My network already has 192.168.1.1 as a firewall and I don't want to unplug my network just to configure a wireless router.

Answer (score 5):

No. The router will only have a single IP address.

Just unplug your workstation from the network and attach to the WRT54g. It'll take you a few minutes to do the configuration, then you can re-connect to the production network.

Keep in mind that you'll want to turn off DHCP on the 54g and assign it a different IP address, lest it wreak havoc on your network when it gets attached.

Comment: No, it won't require a crossover cable. Just plug your workstation into one of the LAN ports ont he 54g.

Comment: You're going to lose all of those connections. If that's a big deal, then find another computer to use for configuration of the router. There's really no way you're going to get around this.